# How to pass a PHP string as JS function parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this PHP code who send an URL as argument to a JS function :

```
<?php
$url="www.google.com";
echo '<input type="submit" name="btnfone" onclick="window.open('.$url.')" class="btn-style2" value="Viewmap"/>';
?>
```

When I test it, nothing append.
But if I change the URL with an integer

```
$url=1234;
```

Then the argument is interpreted.

What's the solution ?

Comment: Hit `Ctrl+U` in your browser and you'll see why.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i  putted www.google.com between " but it don't work.

Comment: Well... think about the difference between `window.open(www.google.com)` and `window.open(1234)`...

Comment: I tried with `window.open("www.google.com")` and it don't work

Comment: Because you don't have a `www.google.com` subdirectory. Don't you mean `http://...` by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add quotes and escape.

```
onclick="window.open(\''.$url.'\')"
```

Comment: this would work, but really... it would be so much better to not do this in an echo....

Comment: Thanks @CayceK it work. I need to do it with an echo cause I get the URL from a file.

Comment: @SachaDee ... you still don't need to echo the whole lot though - you could leave PHP first (`?>`) and do something like `<input type="submit" name="btnfone" onclick="window.open('<?= $url; ?>')" class="btn-style2" value="Viewmap" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try !